# Docker through proxy

Tags: docker, proxy

I did set a proxy at the CLI as following:

```
$ export http_proxy="http://10.20.6.67:1209"
$ export https_proxy="https://10.20.6.67:1209"
$ export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0"
```

I am trying to pull an image from Docker, but it returns the following error:

```
$ docker pull couchdb
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it as described in *[Control Docker with systemd, HTTP/HTTPS proxy](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy)*.

Create a file called **/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf** that adds the HTTP_PROXY environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com"
```

Flush changes:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart Docker:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Now `docker pull` works!